# Chrome no me detecta " ${} "

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Me estoy iniciando en JavaScript y vi que ahora para concatenar strings se puede usar `${}`, el tema es al utilizarlo Chrome no me lo detecta :

```js
 var nicolas ={
  nombre :"Nicolas",
  apellido :"Gigena",
  edad : 19
}

var pepe ={
  nombre :"Pepe",
  apellido:"Lil",
  edad:20
}

function imprimirNombre(persona){
  var {nombre, edad } = persona
  console.log("mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad}")
}

imprimirNombre(nicolas)
imprimirNombre(pepe)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Cuando utilizas interpolación en Javascript necesitas utilizar `` en lugar de "" o ''.

```
console.log(`mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad}`);
```

[Aquí puedes ver más información](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

Answer (score 5):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
var nicolas ={
  nombre :"Nicolas",
  apellido :"Gigena",
  edad : 19
}

var pepe ={
  nombre :"Pepe",
  apellido:"Lil",
  edad:20
}

function imprimirNombre(persona){
  var {nombre, edad } = persona
  console.log(`mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad}`)
}

imprimirNombre(nicolas)
imprimirNombre(pepe)
```

En JavaScript se puede usar la sintaxis `${}` solo cuando declaras el string con comillas invertidas.

En teclados con distribución Latam (America latina):

```
alt gr + } = `
```

Puedes leer un poco [mas sobre strings en JavaScript aquí](https://librosweb.es/tutorial/las-nuevas-cadenas-de-texto-de-javascript-6/).

Comment: es correcto, se utiliza el acento invertido para la evaluacion de strings

Comment: Buena respuesta, te recomiendo que elimines la referencia hacie como producir el caracter `, ya que depende de la distribución de cada teclado :D

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @JuanSalvadorPortugal, la tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez estés buscando esto

```js
var nicolas ={
  nombre :"Nicolas",
  apellido :"Gigena",
  edad : 19
}

var pepe ={
  nombre :"Pepe",
  apellido:"Lil",
  edad:20
}

function imprimirNombre(persona){
  var {nombre, edad } = persona
  console.log("mi nombre es "+persona.nombre+" y tengo "+persona.edad)
}

imprimirNombre(nicolas)
imprimirNombre(pepe)
```

Mando llamar la variable mediante la variable `persona.nombre` como si fuera un JSON

Saludos :)